# C/Fortran 2D arrays (basic)

Tags: c, arrays, fortran

I have a few basic questions about 2D arrays, e.g.:

```
double bn[NNODES][NBASIS]
```

1-How is the declaration in C? And in Fortran?

2-The first [] is for the rows number and the second for columns, both for C and Fortran?

3- When using bn, e.g. bn[i][j], the "i" index is for rows and "j" is for columns? Both in C and Fortran?

4- How is the write/print function (both for C and Fortran) only for one (e.g. i=15) and entire row?

Thanks

Comment: This look like problems for beginning programming class. This is not the place to solve your programming class problems.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the examples are for a square matrix which obscures one issue.  C and Fortran uses different memory layouts for multi-dimensions arrays.  C is row-major, while Fortran is column major.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order.  When working between the languages, it can be convenient to deal with this in the declarations, e.g., in C:

```
double array [20][10];
```

and in Fortran, using the `iso_c_binding` intrinsic module:

```
real (C_DOUBLE), dimension (10,20) :: array
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1-How is the declaration in C? And in Fortran?

In C, you declare a static array as such: `int arr[row][col];`

> 2-The first [] is for the rows number and the second for columns, both for C and Fortran?

It doesn't really matter if you consider the first or second subscript of a 2D array the row or column subscript.  What matters is that you stay within bounds.  `arr[0][0]` to `arr[row - 1][col - 1]`.

> 3- When using bn, e.g. bn[i][j], the "i" index is for rows and "j" is for columns? Both in C and Fortran?

See answer 2.

> 4- How is the write/print function (both for C and Fortran) only for one (e.g. i=15) and entire row?

Use `for` loops to access a single row or column in the array.  For example, to access all the elements in row 0:

```
for(int c = 0; c < col; ++)
    printf("%d\n", arr[0][c]);
```

Comment: @VladimirF Sure, it matters if you're writing something that needs to be compatible with someone else's implementation of 2D arrays, but the question is whether [row] and [column] subscripts are set in stone or not.

Comment: Not somone else's, MATMUL is defined in the Fortran standard.

Answer (score 0):

> 1-How is the declaration in C? And in FORTRAN?

In C

```
double bn[10][10];
```

In FORTRAN

```
double precision bn(10, 10)
```

> 2-The first [] is for the rows number and the second for columns, both for C and Fortran?

Yes.

> 3- When using bn, e.g. bn[i][j], the "i" index is for rows and "j" is for columns? Both in C and Fortran?

Yes.

> 4- How is the write/print function (both for C and Fortran) only for one (e.g. i=15) and entire row?

In FORTRAN

```
do, i=1:10
    do, j=1:10
        write (*,*) bn(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
```

In C

```
for(i = 0; i < 10, i++)
    for(i = 0; i < 10, i++)  
          printf("%f", bn[i][j]);
```

Comment: `double precision bn(10)(10)` - not so much, try `double precision bn(10,10)`.  And to print row `i` `write(*,*) bn(i,:)` will suffice, no loop across the columns necessary.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark; That was a typo. And yes for a fixed row you can do this.